# Is it ok to 301 redirect product-category pages to custom pages?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, seo

I would like to create a custom page in my wordpress, with a custom design and export all the products from a certain category there. However, breadcrumbs from woocommerce will point to the old/normal category archive page, so in order to fix this i would have to 301 redirect it to my custom made page

Will this redirect cause any SEO issues? All the breadcrumbs as well as the breadcrumbs in the structured data will point to a category pages that actually redirects somewhere else.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You typically won't experience too much of an issue if you've correctly 301 redirected the URL. However, it's better to customize an existing page instead of trying to replace it - and as you said, end up with incorrect breadcrumbs, which can make for a confusing user experience.

If you create a child theme, you can create a product archive template for just the one product category. You can then either just place your desired content directly in the template, or if you really want an Editor experience, you could create a Page (being sure to 301 redirect it to the product category, and being sure it never gets listed in any sitemaps) and within your product archive template, query for that Page's contents so you can edit content within wp-admin.